# Mule reinvoke flow in case of exceptions

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am working on a integration that performs a manage file transfer over sftp. 
i am lately seeing a issue, where the destination closes the stream in case of issues, leading to mule complaining of error "Inputstream is Closed". 
I am consdering a exception mechanism to rexecute the flow in case of a exception of type IOException with message InputStream is closed. The flow works fine in case of a success scenario, but in case of a failure [stimulated using a script throwing java.io.exception] the exception handler does not handles the exception and i get following on logs :- 
org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: Failed to dispatch message to error queue after it failed to process.

And the integration terminates posts this.

The exceution is managed in subFlows and the main thread is invoked using a quartz scheduler.

Any help or direction to overcome this issue will help.

thanks
Sk

Comment: Please share your flow xml. Do you have a polling trigger to your flow?

Comment: Assume have to concentrate on settings the timeouts values. Without flows it is difficult to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rollback Exception Strategy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/rollback-exception-strategy) to retry connection few more times.